# Meteor file on new created project is missing

Tags: meteor

I used meteor for the first time yesterday and i was doing well. Today i try to create an new project to follow some tutorials and it was impossible i was receiving this message.

```
'meteor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

but when i try to create a project on ***C:\users\any\AppData\Local.meteor*** the project is successfully created, so i go inside the folder of my new project using `cd newproject` and then type `meteor` and now the meteor should start building application but nothing happening, i again receive the same message

```
'meteor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

someone who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may fix this issue by adding `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\.meteor;` to your `PATH` environment variable.